# Chrome keyboard shortcut overwrite jupyter notebook keyboard shortcuts

Tags: google-chrome, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

I've just recently switched to chrome (I'm using Macos Ventura 13.5.1) and I'm having some problems with its shortcuts overwrite jupyter notebook edit mode keyboard shortcuts. To be detailed, I want to block comment in jupyter notebook, however, when pressing `cmd + /`, it doesn't do anything. If you know any solutions, please help me with it.

What I tried:

1. I ran jupyter notebook in Microsoft Edge and the shortcut `cmd + /` works just fine
2. I disabled all extensions shortcuts so they can't conflict with jupyter nb shortcuts
3. I tried all other possible key combinations including: `ctrl + /`, `shift + /`, `ctrl-cmd + /`, `cmd + +/=`, `ctrl + -`..... but none worked
4. I tried modifying notebook.json as following:

```javascript
{
  "cell": {
    "cm_config": {
      "linenumbers": true
    }
  },
  
  "keys":{
    "edit": {
        "bind": {
            cmd_ctrl + "/": "jupyter-notebook:comment"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

and

```javascript
{
  "cell": {
    "cm_config": {
      "linenumbers": true
    }
  },
  
  "keys":{
    "edit": {
        "bind": {
            cmd + "/": "jupyter-notebook:comment"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

But none of those worked either.